# dnsmasq, have to manually set dns after each reboot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, dhcp, dns

I have a small problem, i'm using dnsmasq and NetworkManager. Every time i reboot, i check the `resolv.conf` file and the nameserver here is always set to `127.0.0.1` (nothing alarming here) except I cannot access internet because the DNS is wrong. If i manually change the dns to mine (`192.168.1.1`) in `resolv.conf`, the requests now works and the access is allowed. How is that possible?

Do you have any tips?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: do you have resolvconf installed? if so, then dnsmasq should be (and does on ALL my systems) using resolvconf output to determine upstream DNS rather than `/etc/resolv.conf` - perhqaps `NetworkManager` breaks this - never used it, so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i'm answering my own question but by doing this post, I knew how to rephrase my research better...
I realised dnsmasq was overwriting the dns configuration, because the local machine was automatically set as the resolver.

Adding: `DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo` in `/etc/default/dnsmasq` solved this issue.

Found this post which explains it better: [Proper way to prevent dnsmasq from overwriting DNS server list supplied by DHCP?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37439/proper-way-to-prevent-dnsmasq-from-overwriting-dns-server-list-supplied-by-dhcp?rq=1)